# Should "Restarting worked for me" be a comment?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, not-an-answer

[The question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542145/eclipse-ide-open-call-hierarchy-is-empty-broken/18204378):

> What should I do, if the "Open Call Hierarchy" is broken (empty for every method in a project)? It is very useful for code navigation, do not know, how to work without it!

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18204378/502950) (now converted to a comment):

> I have had the same issue. Closing and re-opening the project fixed this issue for me. You might want to give that a try.

The comment on the answer (before it was deleted):

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post

Comment: @Servy: saw that after I commented and deleted my comment already. :P

Comment: 3 upvotes and 2 downvotes. Maybe some explanation from downvoters - why do you think it should be a comment?

Comment: That isn't what voting means.

Comment: @GEOCHET - Its mean agree (+) or not (-) or not? =)

Comment: Or it means "This is an unnecessary question". Do you consider this question useful?

Comment: The votes on my answer are whether people agree with my answer or not.

Comment: @GEOCHET ok - good )

Comment: Considering that the person who posted the answer doesn't even have enough rep to comment yet, why was this question even asked? Give the newbie some slack until he has sufficient rep to leave comments. And, if it really is an answer that should be a comment, then maybe a mod can covert it.

Comment: well it really doesn't answered the question neither telling why the problem solved it may possible that he made some changes  and then on closing those automatically reverse

Comment: I want to note that I agree with @gordon, however please people if you see a question where the accepted answer is: "restart the thing" **also close and delete the question** instead of just flagging the non answers.

Comment: Looks like everyone here missed the fact the OP found the solution himself and posted it as a comment to the question.

Comment: Yes, OP accepted an obvious debugging step as answer because it works for him, some users even upvote these answers. Kill the question with fire! /s

Comment: It wasn't really deleted and reposted. The answer was *converted* to a comment by a moderator, after it was flagged as "not an answer".

Comment: @CodyGray the same 2 step operation in 1 step

Comment: @CodyGray but I also didnt know moderators can convert answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer provided is not a great answer, but it is an answer. It could potentially solve the problem described in the question.

Comment: I read that answer as "Have you tried closing and reopening the project? It worked for me." ;-)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: Have you tried closing and reopening the question?

Answer (score 13):

If I had handled that flag, I would have certainly converted it to a comment.

Restarting an application is the [first thing to do whenever something goes wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0). It's troubleshooting 101 and as an answer it is way too generic. It's the type of "answer" you can put below every problem with an application and it will never be "wrong", because it's the reasonable first thing to try.

In case of this particular question restarting worked for the OP giving the answer but [it didn't work for the OP asking the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542145/eclipse-ide-open-call-hierarchy-is-empty-broken/18204378#comment22020748_15542145). This shows how generic that "solution" is because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. And that's why it should be a comment only.

We expect answers to contain factual information about how to solve specific problems. If restarting makes the error go away, it's a magic fix. You are lucky then. But it offers no insight whatsoever into the problem or why the solution works.

Likewise, because "restart your application" is so basic and generic as a "solution" it offers no value whatsoever to future visitors. It's so obvious to try that it doesn't qualify as an answer.

As a rule of thumb: if you dont know what exactly solves a problem but want to make suggestions about what to try, provide them as a comment an if that then turns out to solve the problem, turn it into an answer.

To add some numbers to illustrate that answering "restart your application" is not considered an answer, consider the following 5 posts (you need 10k to view these):

- [Getting errors in Android Project in eclipse even if there is no error in source code or xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543976/getting-errors-in-android-project-in-eclipse-even-if-there-is-no-error-in-source/12543999#12543999)
- [Application running issue in android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469800/application-running-issue-in-android-emulator/11469838#11469838)
- [Sharepoint Timer job creates list item but doesnot fire item event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830943/sharepoint-timer-job-creates-list-item-but-doesnot-fire-item-event-handlers/7830956#7830956)
- [The version of clr.dll in the target does not match the one mscordacwks.dll was built for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784310/the-version-of-clr-dll-in-the-target-does-not-match-the-one-mscordacwks-dll-was/17177533#17177533)
- [phonegap geolocation allways fail on timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859425/phonegap-geolocation-allways-fail-on-timeout/16299335#16299335)

That's five out of many more deleted posts suggesting to restart the application:

[image: Deleted posts suggesting to restart an application]

Comment: You have created a monster now. There are hundreds of "restarting *x* fixed this for me" answers in the not-an-answer queue.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah, but that's a good thing, isn't it?

Comment: Sure, I suppose. I just haven't the magic buttons to deal with them all, and that saddens me :-(

Comment: +1 Basic debuggery is **not** an answer, it's a comment. It should be a "have you tried this?". "Have you tried turning it off and on again" is not an legitimate answer, unless you're from the IT Crowd.

Comment: @Gordon: It's a bit of a mess in the 10k queue right now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193570/is-an-answer-consisting-of-please-restart-technology-in-question-not-an-answer?noredirect=1#comment606465_193570

Comment: @Jimbo Hah, "debuggery", I like it :)

Comment: @Jimbo: Necessary XKCD: http://xkcd.com/806/.