# Is an answer consisting of "Please restart technology-in-question" not an answer?

Tags: discussion, 10k-tools, not-an-answer

The 10k queue is full of not an answer flags on answers containing only "Please restart xyz". It looks like someone did a search and went on a flagging rampage.

How should we be handling these flags? Are these really not an answer, even if accepted, up-voted, and worked for the OP?

EDIT: Here's an example: [EF Power Tools Beta 2 Generate Views gives error: "a constructible type deriving from dbcontext could not be found in the selected file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479975/ef-power-tools-beta-2-generate-views-gives-error-a-constructible-type-deriving/13542600#13542600). There are tons like in the 10k queue right now.

Comment: Care to link an example answer?

Comment: [You are right, someone did a search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193224/should-restarting-worked-for-me-be-a-comment/193335#comment605458_193335).

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9870488/1288

Comment: @Bart: See edit and comments.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Not the best example, since that [started life as a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869574/unintialized-constant-name-of-modeltire-for-elasticsearch/9870488#comment12585024_9869574) and migrated to an answer once it "solved" the problem.

Comment: @DuncanJones How does that make it not a good example? It's been flagged as not an answer.